# Results appear in columns and not rows

Tags: sql, date, transform, rows, columnsorting

In SQL Server, i'm trying create a query, but I need the dates in columns and appear in rows.

The dates that appear are:

**IDNUMBER    STATUS       SETON        WORKFLOWID**

25                      Payed            01/02/2019      1

25                      Received       20/02/2019      1

25                      Payed           05/05/2019      2

25                      Received      10/05/2019      2

40                      Payed           03/03/2019      4

40                      Received      15/03/2019      4

And I want that the rows values appear in the columns:

IDNUMBER    Payed             Received        WORKFLOWID

25                  01/02/2019      20/02/2019             1

25                  05/05/2019      10/05/2019             2

40                  03/03/2019      15/03/2019             4

Who querie I need to create to obtain this dates???

Thanls

Answer (score 1):

corrected "SETON as Received" (marked in Bold)

`````
    From   
    (Select IDNUMBER, SETON  as Received,  WORKFLOWID from tb1 where STATUS = 'Received')a
    left join
    (Select IDNUMBER, SETON  as Payed,  WORKFLOWID from tb1 where STATUS = 'Payed')b
    on a.IDNUMBER = b.IDNUMBER````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select idnumber, workflowid,
       max(case when status = 'payed' then seton end) as payed,
       max(case when status = 'received' then seton end) as received
from t
group by idnumber, workflowid;
```